# Automatically delete rows with a date of -30 days with an onOpen() function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a shared sheet with quite a few remote users, the sheet is a stock sheet for recording best before dates of products.

I have about 50 entries a day that go 'out of date' but would like to keep a months worth of records.

Does anyone know of a script that would delete any rows with a date in column C of today -30 which works with an onOpen function?

I have found several that work but i need one that works onOpen.

Comment: If you've found ones that work why can't you install an `onOpen` trigger for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if the users have Edit access to the spreadsheet and if the script is bound to the spreadsheet:

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  var now = new Date();
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var firstRow = 2;
  var firstCol = 1;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var values = sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
  var daysToMilliseconds = 1000 * 3600 * 24;
  for (var i = numRows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var cellTime = new Date(values[i][2]).getTime();
    var nowTime = now.getTime();
    if ((nowTime - cellTime) / daysToMilliseconds > 30) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i + firstRow);
    }
  }
}
```

If it's a standalone script we are talking about, you should install the `onOpen` trigger, manually or programmatically. For example, if it was programmatically, you could install the trigger by running this function:

```js
function createOnOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("your-spreadsheet-id");
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("deleteOnOpen")
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onOpen()
  .create(); 
}
```

And then you would have to rename your function to `deleteOnOpen`.

#### Reference:

- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks very much @iamblichus - that works for me.  The only problem was that it didn't work with ```var ss = e.source``` so I changed it to ```var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();``` which now works fine.  Thank you